# На сишке падение программы

Tags: c, null, struct

При обращении к элементу структуры (при сравнении его с NULL) происходит завершение программы. Чем можно починить?

```
 if(head->key==NULL)ПолетПрограммы();
```

А да, `struct stName* head;`

```
void add(int h, struct bin* head){
    if(h > head->key){
        if(head->smallest==NULL){
            head->smallest=malloc(sizeof(struct bin));
            head->smallest->key=h;
            head->smallest->biggest=NULL;
            head->smallest->smallest=NULL;
        }
        else add(h, head->smallest);
    }
}
```

Не забывайте инициализировать переменные. У меня не была инициализирована ссылка, и поэтому все летело. После подстановки аперсанда программа ушла гулять по оперативной памяти, скушав много процессорного времени.

Comment: http://i64.fastpic.ru/big/2014/0917/eb/c58ca8e253377fe2496cb2c7ee92d7eb.png
После рекурсивного вызова все валится при любой проверке ключа из головы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте, что head (а это указатель) не указывает в NULL. Если дело не в этом, то дайте пример кода.

Comment: По идее, она NULL быть не должна, вылетает на втором пробеге.

Comment: @Garden Chamber,  
Дак вы проверьте, выполняется ли хотя бы первая строчка?

Comment: При проверке h > head->key вылетает программа.

Comment: @Garden Chamber, просто напишите

     printf("%d %p\n", h, head);

**перед** `if(h > head->key){`

Comment: @avp, Вы читали Update темы? Моя проблема уже решена. При вызове у меня передавлась "голова" с неинициализированными переменными. В них хранились случайные данные из памяти, и они не были NULL-ом. При обращении к этим данным программа падала, выходя за ограничения памяти, т.к. переходила по ссылке.

Comment: @Garden Chamber,

Достижение получено: "Любимые грабли (студент)".